# sort sum of matching fields in a large file

Tags: bash, sorting, csv, awk

I have a large file (around 200 MB) and I need to extract
top 10 (and top n%) most aggregate values for tuples
for example I have a 2 column csv file:

```
c1 c2
----------
a,10
b,20
c,5
d,60
a,20
c,10 
a,20
b,10
```

and I need top 2 records with maximum aggregate c2 values,
in this case i need this output:

```
a,50
d,60
```

As I said the file is too large (500000 long records)
and if I need top 1% or 10% of it I can't just simply use
something like this because it passes the number of unique a,b,c,d,...

```
while read line
do
Sum=$(awk -F, -v inp=$line '$1==inp{x+=$2;}END{print x}' $INPUT_File)
done < firstColumnFile
```

Note that `firstColumnFile` in here is just a temp file I put a,b,c,d,... in it...
my main file which must be processed is INPUT_File

How can I do this with bash, awk using a single pass through the file?

Comment: use the `{}` "code" tool at the top left of the input box to format your code and data. In the meantime, search here for examples with `sort` and `tail -n 10`.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the aggregation with the following `awk` script:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>2{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(k in a)print k","a[k]}' file
a,50
b,30
c,15
d,60
```

Tac on a sort and tail for only `n` valueS:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>2{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(k in a)print k","a[k]}' file | sort -t, -k2 | tail -n 2
a,50
d,60
```

Comment: but isn't this going to take hours? it passes the large file too many times

Comment: @user3144923 nope, seconds at the most. Unlike your solution the `awk` script is linear where as your attempt was quadratic.. you was reading the whole of `$INPUT_FILE` for every line in `firstColumnFile`. You should never use `bash` and `awk` together in this way. Just read the file once with `awk` as it was designed.